# Convert HH:MM values to H in the same column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Is there a way for me to format a column where the values I enter in the format HH:MM (elapsed time, not datetime) are converted to hours in decimal, preferably in the same column via some custom formula?

For example,

| HH:MM | H (Decimal) |
| --- | --- |
| 07:39 | 7.65 |
| 02:15 | 2.25 |
| 06:00 | 6 |

At the moment, I manually calculate the equivalent and enter them into the column but it would be nice to directly copy a timestamp and have the column automatically format it but I couldn't see an option for this in Date/Time formatting settings.

Comment: In Excel, you cannot do this by formatting. You must perform a calculation that does the conversion, and then format that as Number or General. You could do this in an adjacent column, or use a VBA event-triggered macro if it had to be in the same cell.  The latter could be a bit tricky, though.

Comment: What do you mean you enter it in elapsed time, not datetime? I think I'm not understanding your question because you can absolutely use cell formatting to show decimal versions of times...

Comment: @SandPiper This is effectively what I'm asking, can I (either through Google Sheets or Excel), enter something like elapsed hours/mins, i.e. 07:39 h/m, to automatically format to decimal?

Answer (score 4):

Simply multiply your hh:mm durations by 24, ensuring that the cells where you want the decimal hours returned are formatted as 'Number'. Or to force formatting as a number using a formula: `=text(duration_cell*24,"#.##")` where duration_cell is a cell with the duration in hh:mm format.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that I know of because Excel stores times/dates as floats. Each 24 hour period equals `1`, therefore 7:33 equals `.31458` Therefore, you won't be able to do this without a helper column.

You can do this with either @The God of Biscuits answer, or alternatively your helper column can have the formula:

```vb
=(A1*24)
```

and you set that column's cell format to `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

You can aply this formula: `=HORA(A2)+(MINUTO(A2)/60)`

[image]

Comment: This only works in Spanish, what are the English versions of those commands?

Comment: HOUR() and MINUTE()

Comment: This will fail if duration >= 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

All date and time is a format of a double value.
Time is the amount after the comma.
And all in front of comma is days since 00.01.1900.

Meaning 07:37:00 = 0,32 days.

Excel have a ways to pull the amount of hours with **=HOUR**('Your referance date time cell value')

Comment: HOURS function will give wrong answer if duration >= 24 hours

Comment: If you have a start- and a stop datetime - Numbers of Hours is always (Stop - Start) * 24 as there is always 24 hours in one day ;-)